# How can I see the number of shutter actuations for my Canon EOS 350D?

Tags: canon, shutter-actuations, canon-350d

I have a Canon Digital Rebel XT (otherwise known as the EOS 350D). I'd like to find the number of shutter actuations.

I have tried ExifTool, and the ShutterCount is not part Exif information for a Rebel. FileNumber is though. For one of my latest .jpg files, the FileNumber was 425-2556. Does that mean I've used 4 million files? If I took 1000 pictures a day for a year, that would be 365,000 files. So 4 million files would be over 10 years worth.

Comment: I have tried ExifTool, and the ShutterCount is not part Exif information for a Rebel. FileNumber is though. For one of my latest .jpg files, the FileNumber was 425-2556. Does that mean I've used 4 million files?  If I took 1000 pictures a day for a year, that would be 365,000 files.  So 4 million files would be over 10 years worth.

Comment: For later models: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3840/how-can-i-get-the-shutter-actuation-count-for-canon-eos-500d-550d

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not aware of any available software that would give you the shutter count for Canon 350D.

I have used before [EOSInfo Utility](http://astrojargon.net/EOSInfo.aspx) but I am afraid it only supports 40D, 50D, 450D, 500D, 1000D and 5DmkII. I tested it on 40D and 450D and it worked fine. Based on the notes on the EOSInfo website it seems that this information is not available for other models

> The shutter count information is available *only* on Canon DIGIC III/IV DSLRs *except* the 1D* series. This means that EOSInfo will display the shutter counter for the 40D, the 50D, the 450D, 500D, and the 1000D. It will also show the shutter counter for the 5DMkII, but the camera must be power-cycled before the value is updated. The shutter counter will not be displayed (or will be displayed as "0") on the 1D*, 5D, 10D, 20D, 30D, 300D, 350D, and 400D.  It's not that I have anything against the owners of those cameras, but simply that the Canon SDK does not support retrieving the shutter count for them. UPDATE (08/06/2009): Apparently, Canon has removed the facility for checking the shutter count on the 500D. More news when I learn something.

I am not sure if this refers to the EOSInfo software or the availability of that information in general

Comment: Worth noting that there's a mac version too called 40D Shutter Count linked from the EOSInfo Utility page.

Comment: I tried with 1100D(T3) and the camera just got hanged. Any other way to check it ?

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to figure shutter count on my EOS 350d.

1. Download Opanda IEXIF Viewer, yes it does store total number of shots taken with eos 350d!!! - but not in clear text
2. Open last image shot
3. At line 0093 in opanda exif viewer there are some numbers. I saved lots of pictures in my computer, including the first ones shot... opened the first image ever shot with my camera (file number one) and I found this numbers 32, 6400, 1, ...
   Opened file number 97 shot and found the numbers like this: 32, 6400, 97, ...
   Opened file number 199 shot and found the numbers like this: 32, 6464, 199, ...
   Opened file number 252 and found: 32, 6528, 252
   Opened file number 258 and found 32, 6529, 2 So third number goes until 256 and then increments second number and starts from 1
   Picture 314 shows 32, 6593, 58
   Picture 734 shows 32, 6850, 222
   Picture 838 shows 32, 6915, 70
   **So every 100 shots, camera increments second number by 64, at 256 shots it increments second number by 1 and resets third number.**
4. Roughly if you **take second number, substract 6400 from it and then divide the result by 64 and then multiply the result by 100** you will get a number that is very close to the real number of total shots taken by EOS 350d. - it is not exact because would imply more complicated math and it's not the case... as this result is pretty close to reality

   ---> This only works with 350D <---

If that is correct then right way to calculate number of shots are:

> *second number* - (x*128) = 6400
>
> 128x = *second number* - 6400
>
> x = [*second number* - 6400]/128
>
> And then multiply x * 256 = total number of shots

Because every 256 shots second number goes down by 128.

Comment: Sounds like a "raw" non-standard EXIF tag that the software can show the undecoded values for.

Comment: it's real and it's working. Judging by this criteria, the last picture taken by me the other day shows something near 47.000 shots, whitch is pretty close to what I thought for my camera.

Comment: Make an excel file to guess the number of shutter actuations to match with the line 0093

Answer (score 2):

As for the filenames go, I think in the number ID 425-2556, "25" is repeated. So the number of the photo would be 42556. 100-0001 would be first, 101-0100 would be 100th etc. On some cameras the first three digit number are in the folder name (e.g. CANON-425) and the rest is in the filename (e.g. IMG-2556). There are only 100 photos per folder. So the folder number counts how many "hundreds of photos" have you made.

Comment: Filenames aren't accurate since depending on how the camera is configured the filenames might either roll over or automatically reset each time a new card/folder begins.

Comment: Sure. I was just commenting that the given number was more like 42 thousand than 4 million and trying to explain the structure of filename (perhaps someone might use it).  However, if the camera was set to roll over on each card change, I doubt it would reach the given filename. Of course, when buying used camera, I would not relay on this number!

Answer (score 1):

This page might help http://dptnt.com/2007/06/how-to-find-out-the-total-shutter-actuations-of-your-dslr/

Answer (score 1):

I have previusly used [Opanda IExif](http://www.opanda.com/en/iexif/index.html) to get this kind of information. The program is freeware and will show you (among other things) how many shots that you have taken with your camera based on the shutter count attribute recorded on a photo’s [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) information.

After you have pressed "Open" and find a recently taken photo, look for `Total Number of Shutter Releases for Camera`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called photome that will allow you to access the Exif data of a picture and will also give you the shutter actions in that data.

Answer (score 0):

I know the info from here : http://www.twam.info/software/read-out-canon-eos-7d-shuttercount-on-os-x works on the the XSi, T1i and 7D. This also assumes you have Linux or OSX. I would guess/hope it would work on the 350D.