# How do I find how many pictures have been taken with a Canon EOS1000d?

Tags: software, metadata, shutter-actuations, canon-1000d

I have tried looking in the software that came with it, but with no luck so far. This is probably very basic... I would really value any help please.

Comment: OK myshuttercount.com stays as a black screen when jpeg is loaded......15min later nothing has happened. The image number attached to the image shouldn't be the shutter count cos you can change that(? can't you....she says further displaying her ignorance!!)

Comment: Yes, the image number can be reset, roll over after 10K and so forth, so not reliable.

Comment: See also [this for the 500/550D](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3840/how-can-i-get-the-shutter-actuation-count-for-canon-eos-500d-550d), and links in that question for even older models. A couple of those solutions may work for the 1000D, but I can't confirm.

Answer (score 2):

The shutter count should be in the EXIF information, which you can read with [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/) or other EXIF readers.

Or you can upload a JPG to [myshuttercount](http://myshuttercount.com/) and it will tell you.

Comment: Thanks everyone- finally sorted using the EOS utility. Really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This only works if you have the camera set on continuous file numbering. Hit the button on the camera to view images. There should be a number in the upper right of the screen. The 1000d starts at 100-0001, and counts up to 100-9999. at 10,000 images, you should see 101-0001.

Even if you delete an image from your camera and take another, the counter continues. For example, if your last image was 102-4563, and you delete it, the next image will be 102-4564.

When you're viewing the memory card on your computer, the card is named EOS_Digital by default. Open the folder "DCIM." The camera splits images into folders for every 10,000 pictures starting with 100CANON, then 101CANON. If you're viewing _MG_4563.JPG in the folder 103CANON, you've taken 34,563 pictures.

Comment: so what about when the file numbering is reset?

Comment: There's some software out there, like ShutterCount, but I've never tried it.  http://www.learningdslrvideo.com/shutter-count-revisited/

Comment: This isn't necessarily true - for example, because the first card I ever put in my camera was one I'd previously used on my Canon point and shoot, the first image from my 550D was 100-6543 or so.

Comment: That's not sound right. The first 3 digit "100, 101...104,105,106" is just the continute up counted Files number every time you create new select foder.