# Is Magic Lantern giving incorrect shutter counts on my Canon 500D?

Tags: shutter, canon-500d, magic-lantern

I bought a new camera (500D) and have had it for about 4 days. I have installed the latest version of Magic Lantern on it to get a little boost, but when I got into shutter count it gives me 14k (13988 + 177)??! in 4 days (I took about 200 photos)...

My 500D is brand new (well, I bought it in store as new, with box closed). Is it possible that the count on MagicLantern is not accurate on 500D??! Or is there some other software or trick to get proper shutter count?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the shutter actuation count for Canon EOS 500D/550D?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3840/how-can-i-get-the-shutter-actuation-count-for-canon-eos-500d-550d)

Answer (score 1):

Few remarks:

1. You won't find any shutter count in metadata.
2. Canon cameras may be sold with significant shutter count, as part of their testing / quality check.

You want to try [EOSInfo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/canon-eos-digital-info/) (which works) or directly write your own program with [Canon's SDK](https://developers.canon-europe.com/s/article/How-to-get-access-camera). Then you'll be able to tell if EOSInfo and ML are giving the same shutter count or not.

> Canon doesn’t have shutter count included on the EXIF information of
> an image file, as opposed to Nikon and Pentax. There’s no official
> Canon based application to find the shutter count for an EOS DSLR.
> However, there are a few free tools that may help you to do this. They
> provide some details about the camera, including product Name,
> firmware version, battery level, shutter Counter, date/time, and
> owner/artist/copyright strings.

Comment: 14K sounds like quite a lot of shutter releases just for testing purposes isn't it? And do they not reset the shutter count before the camera leaves the factory?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a shutter count website like this one:

http://www.camerashuttercount.com/

By uploading a picture it will give you the count and you can compare it against the one given on Magic Lantern.

If the first count was correct, I would try speaking to wherever you bought it from as that may suggest it wasn't brand new at all, although for 14k I would expect some other indications of use.

Comment: Have you actually tried this with a 500D photo? I don't believe that Canon include the shutter counts in metadata.